# Is there still integrated login on the iPhone for Google, Facebook, and Twitter?

Tags: ios, facebook, google

It seems that since iOS 11, integrated login for Facebook and Twitter was removed (which was introduced in iOS 6).

What about for Google?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple has [removed the Facebook and Twitter integration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/290600/279727) starting with iOS 11.

Google integration has never been available in iOS in the manner similar to how Facebook and Twitter was. However, it has been always possible to add a Google account on your iPhone to access Mail, Contacts and Notes within the 1st party apps. The option can be found Passwords & Accounts section of iOS Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

Was Google ever officially integrated for login?

## App Extensions

Apple now recommend third parties implement [app extensions](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/) to share and integrate into iOS.